# How long does it take geoPy to geocode my addresses?

Tags: python, geopy

```
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = 'application')

address_latitude = []
address_longitude = []
address_list = list(df4['full_address'])

for address in address_list:
    location = geolocator.geocode(address,timeout = None)
    address_latitude.append(location.latitude)
    address_longitude.append(location.longitude)
```

It has already been about 4 hours running, just wondering if there is something wrong with my code or it's normal for GeoPy to take this long.

Comment: Your timeout is set to None, meaning that it will forever try to connect to or find a GPS signal. You could be in a room with an especially bad connection to any GPS satellites, which means that it could just run forever. If you want to 'fix' that, you can try setting a value for that argument, or going outside and test it there. Some buildings will completely isolate those types of signals. Especially reinforced concrete, which will just act as a sort of Faraday Cage. If you can try this and confirm, I will put it in the answer block.

Comment: How big is your address list? If the time per address is over a second, there is probably a connection problem (or maybe invalid key, etc.), would you see timeouts?